# If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x=0$ and $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, then $f$ is continuous at every point in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Let $f$ be a function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the additive condition $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. I have already proved that $f(0)=0$ and $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, therefore I will take these facts as given.

I want to show that if $f$ is continuous at $x=0$, then $f$ is continuous at every point in $\mathbb{R}$. I will use the following **definition of continuity**: A function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at a point $c \in A$ if, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $|x-c|<\delta$ it follows that $|f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon$.

**My Proof Attempt**: Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $x=0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - 0| = |x| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(0)| < \epsilon$. Since $f(0) = 0$, we have $$|x| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)| < \epsilon. \hspace{1em} (1)$$

Let $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ with $y_0 \neq 0$. We want to show that $f$ is continuous at $y_0$. We have (for $a \in \mathbb{R}$) $$|a - y_0| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(a - y_0)| < \epsilon \hspace{1em}(2)$$

by (1). The additive condition gives $|f(a-y_0)| = |f(a) - f(y_0)|$. Substituting this into (2) gives $$|a - y_0| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(a) - f(y_0)| < \epsilon$$

So, by definition of continuity, $f$ is continuous at $y_0$.

Comment: Seems correct to me! 
(I would maybe start the proof with "Let $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ ... continuous at $y_0$" and then continue from there with "Let $\epsilon > 0$. ...", but that's just a matter of taste. You could also leave out the "with $y_0 \neq 0$ as this is not necessary for the rest of the proof)

Comment: $f(x)$ continuous at $x=0$ then $f(x)+f(a)=f(x+a)$ continuous at $x=0$ then $f(x)$ continuous at $x=a$.

Comment: In your definition of continuity, you have missed out the requirement that $x\in A$. Otherwise $f(x)$ is undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof looks fine to me, but could be a little better structured. Here's how I would do it:

> Proposition: Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous at $x=0$ and satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is continuous at each $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$.

*Proof*: As you have already shown, $f(0)=0$ and $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Let $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ and $f(0)=0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have that $$|x|<\delta\implies |f(x)|<\epsilon.$$ Now if $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|x-x_0|<\delta$, we have that $$|f(x-x_0)|=|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$$ using your above observations. Since $\epsilon>0$ was chosen arbitrarily, this shows directly from the definition that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ (for any $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$), and we are done.